# How to get Listview selected item index from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, listview, indexing

I have created a program in which you can save text from textboxes to xml file and show them in a listview.

The problem is that in another form I call the xml file and from a TextBox I make a search in the XML documents with this code:

```
  var q = from el in doc.Root.Elements("Register")
                    let str = el.Element("Name").Value
                    where str.ToLower().Equals(textBox1.Text)
                    select new ListViewItem(el.Elements().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray());

            myList.Items.AddRange(q.ToArray());
```

Everything works fine and I have my info in listview, but when I click the item on Listview, I don't get the original item index but I get 0, so I have all information for Index 0 and not for selecteditem in Listview.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The repaint of the form with the listbox isn't being called.  The normal trick to force a refresh is to set the listview datasource to null and then back to your list with the data.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it? I'm new in programming.

Comment: I think the best way of getting new index is to get the item count of the listview.  The new index will be the count minus one.

Comment: Can you  show it with a code because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Selected  = true;

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for.

the problem is that the index in the XML file is 15. But when i call it by filtering the text, it is in the first row in listview, and when you select it, it has the index 0 which means it is another element

Comment: The get the index before adding the xml.  Then set the index to one greater than the index before adding.  If this doesn't work I think the filtering is the issue.  You need another column in the list view that contains the xml element number.  You are using AddRange which adds the new item to the end of the collection.  You could use InsertAt() which will add in the middle of the collection.